# How to avoid data repetition in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to populate the text from the bootstrap modal. I have appended the ajax response to the bootstrap modal, but when ever someone click on the select value the data will repeatedly added to the bootstrap modal.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mwfbs3bk/10/

```
<div>
<label for="name" style="margin: 0px;">EMP NAME</label>
<input type="text" class="input-normal" id="empname" style="line-height: initial; margin-left: 6px;">


<button type="button" id="nameValue" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="#fee-details" data-toggle="modal">Select Value</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="fee-details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fee-details-label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="records_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>UID</th>
    </tr>
</table>        
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nameValue").click(function(){

  var response = '[{"rank":"9", "content":"Alon", "UID":"5" }';
response += ',{"rank":"6","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]';
response = $.parseJSON(response);

$(function () {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.rank),
        $('<td>').text(item.content),
        $('<td>').text(item.UID)).appendTo('#records_table');
       $("#records_table tbody td").on('click', function() {                   $("#empname").val($(this).text());       
       $('#fee-details').modal('hide');
              });
    });
});

    });

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
}); 
});
```

**Actual script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         $('#getReferenceID').click(function() {
             $("#myModal1").on("show.bs.modal", function(){
                 $("#records_table tbody").empty(); 
            var selectedClass = $("#className option:selected").val();
            var selectedExamType = $("#examType option:selected").val();
                if (selectedClass === ""&& selectedExamType === "") {
                    alert('Please Select Above two dropdowns');
                    return false;
                    } 

                else 

                    {

                                $.ajax({
                                        type : 'POST',
                                        url : 'searchStudentToEditMarks',
                                        dataType : 'JSON',
                                        data : {
                                            className : $("#className option:selected").val(),
                                            examType : $("#examType option:selected").val()
                                                },
                                    success : function(data,success) {
                                        alert(success);
                                        console.log(data)


                                        $.each(data,function(index) {                                           
                                            var newRowContent = "<tr><td>"+data[index]+"</td></tr>";
                                            $("#records_table tbody").append(newRowContent);
                                             $("#records_table tbody td").on('click', function() {

                                                alert($(this).text());
                                                $("#studentReferencID").val($(this).text());
                                                $("#myModal1").modal('hide'); 
                                            }) 



                                         });

                                    },
                                });

                            }
                      });
                 });
         });
```

Comment: This is my expectation http://jsfiddle.net/mwfbs3bk/17/

Comment: same thing am expecting from server why sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfbs3bk/16/)

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fee-details").on("show.bs.modal", function(){
        var response = '[{"rank":"9", "content":"Alon", "UID":"5" }';
        response += ',{"rank":"6","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]';
        response = $.parseJSON(response);

        $(function () {
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').text(item.rank),
                $('<td>').text(item.content),
                $('<td>').text(item.UID)).appendTo('#records_table tbody');

            });
        });
    });

    $("#fee-details").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
            $("#records_table tbody").empty();
    });

});
```

I Added a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` for a better targetting.

When you open the modal, the `<tbody>` will be emptied by calling `.empty()` and then repopulated. Also, the event used is `show.bs.modal`

Comment: i want to empty after populatation of textbox

Comment: @srinivasgowda Updated, now the texbox are emptied after the modal is closed

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('#getReferenceID').click(function() {
        $("#myModal1").on("show.bs.modal", function(){
            $("#records_table tbody").empty(); 
        }); 
        var selectedClass = $("#className option:selected").val();
        var selectedExamType = $("#examType option:selected").val();
        if (selectedClass === ""&& selectedExamType === "") {
            alert('Please Select Above two dropdowns');
            return false;
        }   
        else 
        {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'searchStudentToEditMarks',
                dataType : 'JSON',
                data : {
                    className : $("#className option:selected").val(),
                    examType : $("#examType option:selected").val()
                },
                success : function(data,success) {
                    alert(success);
                    console.log(data)

                    $.each(data,function(index) {                                           
                        var newRowContent = "<tr><td>"+data[index]+"</td></tr>";
                        $("#records_table tbody").append(newRowContent);

                        $("#records_table tbody td").on('click', function() {
                            alert($(this).text());
                            $("#studentReferencID").val($(this).text());
                            $("#myModal1").modal('hide'); 
                        }) 
                    });                                 
                },
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this code to your click function (*Before your click ajax call*):

```
$("#records_table").html("<tr><th>Rank</th><th>Content</th><th>UID</th></tr>")
```

**Explanation:**

This effectively resets the html table beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

JUST a flag **counter** to your code it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter=0;
    $("#nameValue").click(function(){
if(counter<1){
  var response = '[{"rank":"9", "content":"Alon", "UID":"5" }';
response += ',{"rank":"6","content":"Tala","UID":"6"}]';
response = $.parseJSON(response);

$(function () {
    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.rank),
        $('<td>').text(item.content),
        $('<td>').text(item.UID)).appendTo('#records_table');

    });
});
  }    
    counter++;
    alert(counter);
    });
});


$("#records_table tbody td").on('click', function() {
alert('hi');
    $("#empname").val($(this).text());
});
```

Hope it will work.